# Issue publishing report to Power BI Workspace

Tags: azure, reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I created a report using Power BI desktop APP. Publishing the report from Desktop application doesn't publish report to PowerBI workspace in azure.

Here is report that I uploaded using Desktop app
[image]

I used this article to get my uploaded report [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/] from my Power BI embedded but the code doesn't return any report

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not publish a report into power bi embedded with the desktop application.  The power bi desktop will publish reports into the "power bi service" not power bi embedded.

You need to use the "Provision Sample" from the application on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/).

When you run the provision sample choose option 6 to "import" your pbix file into the workspace you have created in power bi embedded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay. So if I want to I consume report that got publish to "power bi service" in my Web application without making that report available in Public gallery what shoud I do?

Comment: If you want to integrate a report from the power bi service into your web app have a look here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Just to increase my understanding what is the difference in Power Bi service and Power BI embeded apart power BI embedded being part of a subscription in azure.

Comment: Based on what I think you are trying to accomplish the biggest difference for your case is that if you go with the PowerBI service each user you want to view the report will need to have a PowerBI license and the report would need to to be shared with that user.  Then when displaying the report it is actually going to need to generate a token based on that users credentials.  PowerBI Embedded uses an access key to generate a token to view the report.  This means you can display the report to any user visiting the website.

Comment: That was very helpful. I'll prefer using PowerBI Embedded in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The Power BI Embedded team also recently released a Node based command line tool that will allow you to import PBIX files into your Power BI workspace collection in Azure.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli

```
npm install -g powerbi-cli

powerbi import -c <collection> -w <workspaceId> -k <accessKey> -f <file> -n [name]
```

Comment: that tool is now deprecated